# SQL Server Driver for Linux 10 and armv7l?

Tags: sql-server, linux, pyodbc, armv7

I want to write a Python script which is connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server database on a remote server from a RevolutionPi running Linux 10 with `armv7l` architecture.

First I installed the Microsoft ODBC 18 using the instructions below (for Debian 10)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Csuse12-13-install%2Crhel7-offline

The last command (`sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18`) results in the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql18
```

I looked at the requirements here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/system-requirements?view=sql-server-ver16#operating-system-support

Here I start to have issues understanding how it works in a deeper way.
It says that `arm64` architecture is supported. Since I am using `armv7l`, I assume that this is the reason I cannot install the package?

Is there any way I can still connect with the database using Python?

Comment: Indeed, https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql18/ only contains `amd64` architecture packages.

Comment: That error says there's no such package *for your architecture*. Looking at the [Debian downloads](https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql18/) I see they're all AMD64

Comment: Debian *does* have a ARM64 build, from version 18.1, however, that is on Debian 11 only, not Debian 10.: *"The ARM64 architecture on Red Hat 8, 9, Debian 11, and Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 are supported starting with version 18.1."* Checking the [packages](https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql18/) confirms there are ARM64 versions. If you want to use ODBC on Debian, you'll need to first upgrade to Debian 11.

Comment: armv7 is a 32-bit architecture - why does your Raspberry Pi think it's 32-bit? oic... "RevolutionPi" isn't really a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Raspbian may be a 32-bit OS but the CPU is 64-bit. If a 64-bit OS is installed, you can install the ODBC driver and even SQL Server itself or at least, the Azure SQL Edge version. For 32-bit CPUs you'll have to use something like FreeTDS. Or set up a web service on a hub device and have the RevoPis push data to it. That's probably a lot *lighter* than maintaining a database connection anyway